# How to prevent a decimal number being rounded to a whole number?

Tags: matlab, integer, decimal-point

I am using this code to get the numeric data from the file I am studying:

```
[FileName,PathName]= uigetfile('*.txt*','Files to Study');

%fullfile puts pathname and filename into one file so it can be used to
%import data from the chosen file 
file =fullfile(PathName,FileName);

A = [];
fid = fopen(file);

tline = fgets(fid);
while ischar(tline)
    parts = textscan(tline, '%d;');
    if numel(parts{1}) > 0
        A = [ A ; parts{:}' ];
    end
    tline = fgets(fid);

end

fclose(fid);
 X = A(:,2)
 Y = A(:,7)
```

It works fine, but the issue I am having is: when the numbers are displayed in the command window they have been rounded from numbers with decimal points to whole numbers.

For example from:

```
165.98  
166.38  
166.78  
167.18  
167.57  
167.97  
168.37  
168.77  
169.17  
169.56  
169.96  
170.36  
170.76  
171.16  
171.55  
171.95
```

to this:

```
 166  
 166  
 167  
 167  
 168  
 168  
 168  
 169  
 169  
 170  
 170  
 170  
 171  
 171  
 172
```

Is there some change I could make to my code to display the original data rather that the rounded whole numbers?

Comment: The `%d` is the issue when used with `textscan`. Try something like `%f`.

Comment: @Divakar I had a feeling it was to do with the %d, that worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: We gotta take care of feelings! :)